# NPM cannot install module, permission denied with mkdir

Tags: node.js, npm, permissions, electron, mkdir

I am attempting to globally install the electron module with npm on OS X Sierra.  When I run

```
sudo npm install electron -g
```

I get

```
/usr/local/bin/electron -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/cli.js

> electron@1.7.5 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/install.js:48
  throw err
  ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/dist'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@1.7.5 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@1.7.5 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ianwise/.npm/_logs/2017-08-10T22_16_42_927Z-debug.log
```

The problem seems to be a permission denied when npm runs mkdir...  But I'm running this with sudo, so why is this a problem?

Comment: Is selinux getting in the way?

Comment: @BobVale I am not familiar with selinux, sorry, is there a way I can check?

Comment: Sorry missed osx part don't think it has it.

Comment: I've had weird permission denied errors like that for other packages which went away when I made sure nodes and non were up to date.

Comment: @BobVale I'm currently running on the latest version of Node (v8.3.0) and nm (v5.3.0), but still no luck, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're running as root. run the following command.

```
npm config set unsafe-perm true

sudo npm install electron -g
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue with electron.

Assuming you have checked that the relevant directories are writable with:

> $ ls -l

In the end I tried *without* sudo and it worked...!

> $ npm install electron -g

The process completed with a message saying:

> npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.

I just deleted the package-lock.json file

For me, the process also completed with a message saying:

> npm update check failed

I followed the instructions at [Ubuntu: npm update failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925545/npm-update-check-failed#935194) to fix this